# Missing FilterList in Asterisk AMI (manager)

Tags: asterisk, amazon-ami, asteriskami

I can't exec AMI **Action: FilterList** in asterisk 13.

[https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+ManagerAction_FilterList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od6lo.png)

[image]

I know is because I'm missing a module, an app or a res from de **modules.conf**, but i can't find which one.

Any idea?

```
CLI> manager show commands
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can check module

```
[arheops@pro-sip]# grep FilterList /usr/src/asterisk-13.24.0/*/*c -Ri
/usr/src/asterisk-13.24.0/main/manager.c:                       <ref type="manager">FilterList</ref>
/usr/src/asterisk-13.24.0/main/manager.c:       <manager name="FilterList" language="en_US">
```

Comment: It founded the description of the function. But what module do I need to load? of course I have the manager loaded! I can do a lot of commands but FilterLists.

Comment: It is in core. However if search via COMPILED modules, there are no such function. So likly it removed and that not in documentation (yet). You can ask in digium list.